Angular Firebase Authentication error Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-email)
I'm trying to register user and i got error:
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-email).
at createErrorInternal (index-a694d6c6.js:503:41)
at _fail (index-a694d6c6.js:471:11)
Here's my code.
**
register.component.ts**
    export class RegisterComponent {
  fb = inject(FormBuilder);
  http = inject(HttpClient);
  authService = inject(AuthService)
  router = inject(Router);
  
  form = this.fb.nonNullable.group({
    username: ['', Validators.required],
    email: ['', Validators.required],
    password: ['', Validators.required]
  });

  onSubmit(): void{
    const rawForm = this.form.getRawValue()
    this.authService.register(rawForm.email, rawForm.username, rawForm.password).subscribe(() => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
    })
  }
}

auth.service.ts
import { inject, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Auth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword,updateProfile } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { from, Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService{
    firebaseAuth = inject(Auth)

    register(
        email: string, 
        username:string, 
        password:string): Observable<void>{
        const promise = createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            this.firebaseAuth,
            email,
            password
        ).then(response => updateProfile(response.user, {displayName: username}));

        return from(promise);
    }
}

When I add
    this.authService.register('test@example.com', 'testUser', 'testPassword123')
  .subscribe({
    next: () => this.router.navigateByUrl('/'),
    error: (error) => console.error('Direct registration error:', error)
  });

to onSubmit, no problem then so firebase works corectly.
